# Bluetooth headphones doesn't work after suspension

Tags: suspend, bluetooth, headphones

I have a problem with my August EP650: after each suspension, the headphones stops working. I found many solutions here and I tried all of them without any results (turn off the bluetooth, kill all the processes, restart pulseaudio). I also tried to disable the bluetooth on my mainboard, and buy an external bluetooth adaptor, but I still have the same problem, even if I unplug the adaptor and plug it again.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and a Lenovo idea pad flex 15. I also tried with another bluetooth headphone set, different brand and model, and I have the same problem. Could someone please help me?

Comment: I have a similar problem. Workaround is: `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth`

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working for me. Still the same problem. Thank you.